# What is this called in the GUI Framework Tag Form toolbox? (see picture)

Tags: c#, user-interface

I would like to know what the section highlighted in red is called in the c# form box:
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's a DataGrid i guess...

Comment: Remove the language tag. It's irrelevant. Instead add the GUI Framework Tag - WinForms/WPF

Comment: Looking at the checkbox and the smallimage under the common header of column 1 it most certainly is a ListView in View=Details mode..

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about WinForms, this looks like a [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) with its `View` property set to [`Details`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.view.aspx).

> A `ListView` control allows you to display a list of items with item text and, optionally, an icon to identify the type of item. For example, the Windows Explorer list of files is similar in appearance to a `ListView` control.

It *could* be anything else, like a `DataGridView` or a third-party component, but the *lightweight* style looks more like a `ListView`.